# Login loop after installing NVIDIA driver in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04

I have got Ubuntu 16.04.1 as OS and the graphics card GeForce GTX 780M. I have been trying to install the NVIDIA driver for my graphics card. But after installation I get login loop.

I downloaded the driver from http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/106780/en-us

I have looked at the similar questions (like [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) and [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)) here but nothing helped. I tried:

1) to disable nouveau

2) to install the NVIDIA drivers from ppa:

```
$ apt-cache search nvidia-* | grep -P "^nvidia-[0-9]+\s"
nvidia-304 - NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.131
nvidia-331 - Transitional package for nvidia-331
nvidia-340 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96
nvidia-346 - Transitional package for nvidia-346
nvidia-352 - Transitional package for nvidia-361
nvidia-355 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 355.11
nvidia-358 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 358.16
nvidia-361 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.45.18
nvidia-364 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 364.19
nvidia-367 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.44
nvidia-370 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 370.23
```

I've tried all of them without a success.

3) to reinstall xorg, xserver-xorg, unity, ubuntu-desktop

4) even to reinstall Ubuntu

But the problem is not solved yet.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I have already tried the recommendations there. It didn't work for me. Probably I should provide additional information about the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the other answers' suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, I have. But they didn't help me.

Comment: Hmm. Try using `nvidia-367` if you haven't. I need to update my answer.

Comment: I have tried particularly `nvidia-367` and `nvidia-370`. It didn't help either.

Comment: Did this work before installing any proprietary drivers?

Comment: All I did is I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. After that Ubuntu worked fine but there was no nvidia driver. Since that moment I've been trying to install this driver without a luck. I haven't installed anything else yet. Without the driver I can log in.

Comment: Did you follow my answer exactly?

Comment: And Secure Boot is off?

Comment: Thanks Zacharee1. I didn't save changes in BIOS when I was switching Secure Boot. It solved the problem.